# How can I send a post request to check-runs on github API with customized headers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, github-api

Reading the API of Github, it demands a custom headers : "vnd.github.antiope-preview+json"; Using spring boot.

I always get 415 Unsupported Media Type eventhough that's what's mentioned in the github API page.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","vnd.github.antiope-preview+json")));
headers.setContentType();
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(str,headers);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

For information , I did it on postman with the same headers.